# Apache Flink Exception Handling

Tags: apache-flink, data-processing

I wrote a job and submitted to standalone cluster. But i want to catch and handle all exceptions. I registered my exception handler like this but seems not working.

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler());
```

I dont want to monitor them from rest endpoints.